# C - Problems with indexes

Tags: c

So I am making this simple sorting algorithm that puts the numbers in an array to be in ascending order.

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int x,smallest,z,n,count;
    int * numbers = NULL;
    printf("Sisestage arvude hulk: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    numbers = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    if(numbers==NULL){
        return -1;
        }
    for(count=0;count<n;count++){
        printf("Arv %d: ",count+1);
        scanf("%d",&numbers[count]);
        }
    smallest = numbers[0];
    for(count=0;count<n;count++){
        printf("Number %d  Index %d\n",numbers[count],count);
        if(numbers[count]<smallest)
            smallest = numbers[count];
            z = count;
        }
    /*numbers[0] = smallest;
    numbers[z] = x;*/
    printf("Smallest: %d, It's index: %d Array size: %d\n",smallest,z,n);
    }
```

The problem here is that when the program is finished, z = the last index in the array for some reason.
The z = count is in a if statement that should help this kind of thing not happen, yet it still does. Why is that?

Comment: That why you should learn indentation, Here is a gift for you ["Indenting C Programs"](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to enclose the if-block in braces:

```
if(numbers[count]<smallest) {
        smallest = numbers[count];
        z = count;
}
```

Therefore, in your case, `z = count` is *always* executed.

Also, `z` is *uninitialized* if the first element `numbers[0]` happens to be the smallest,
therefore you should initialize it with

```
 smallest = numbers[0];
 z = 0;
```

Comment: Hah...  thanks! Such a stupid typo and so much hassle because of it.

Comment: Hmm. haccks, yes index seems to be some random number when I enclose it in brackets.

Comment: use a proper indentation format (see the answer), and it will look obvious.

Comment: @Veske: You also have to initialize z.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets `{}`with your `if` when you can have more than ONE statement.

That should fix it.

Solution:

```
if(numbers[count]<smallest) {
        smallest = numbers[count];
        z = count; }
```

Comment: The trailing close brace at the end of a line is not a desirable layout. In fact, it is positively repulsive.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(numbers[count]<smallest)
            smallest = numbers[count];
            z = count;
```

is the same as:

```
if(numbers[count]<smallest)
{
     smallest = numbers[count];
}
z = count;
```

So it's a parentheses problem